# Spring @AspectJ: Advice not applied

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm trying to weave in code before the call of `start();`

This is the TestClass I want to advice:

```
package com.test;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TestClass().start();
    }
    private void start() {

        System.out.println("Test started");
    }
}
```

This is the aspect including the advice:

```
package com.test;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAspect {

    @Before("call(void com.test.TestClass.start())")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("logBefore() is running");
    }

}
```

This is my spring.xml:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
```

I have also tried to name the beans explicitly in the XML like this:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="test" class="com.test.TestClass" />
<bean id="aspect" class="com.test.LogAspect" />
```

This is my project setup (I'm using the Spring Tool Suite version 3.1.0):

[image: Project setup]

The result is that TestClass.start is called just fine, but the advice is not applied.

What do I have to change so the advice is applied?

Thanks.

**Edit**: I finally got it to work:

After editing my code according to your suggestions I had a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/). This led me to let my TestClass **implement an interface**. And that fixed the problem.

Here is my final setup:

[image: final setup]

The TestClass including its interface:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

interface TestClass {
    void start();
}

public class TestClassImpl implements TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "Spring-Config.xml");

        TestClass t1 = (TestClass) appContext.getBean("myTest");
        t1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

The aspect:

```
package com.test;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LogAspect {
    @Before("execution(void com.test.TestClass.start(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("logging before "
                + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

And the Spring-Config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>    
    <bean id="myTest" class="com.test.TestClassImpl" />
    <bean id="logAspect" class="com.test.LogAspect" />

</beans>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did get your code working although I did use Maven to do the actual weaving.

Comment: @Reimeus: Could you please send me your Maven project to my email address? I want to figure this out.

Comment: All you need is the POM, here is a [good example](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `call` AspectJ pointcut applys when the method is *called* from another class. As you're calling this directly yourself you should use an *execution* pointcut, so change:

```
@Before("call(void com.test.TestClass.start())")
```

to

```
@Before("execution(void com.test.TestClass.start())")
```

Also let the `Spring` create the bean instead of creating one directly yourself.

---

*Aside:* Note, you can keep your `Spring` XML files separate from your source files in `src/resources` and they will be picked up by `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.

Comment: Also instantiate the `Test` class through the Spring application context, not by calling `new`.